# in Actionscript, How to turn off 'Microphone'?

Tags: actionscript-3

in Actionscript, I can turn off webcam by

```
video.attachCamera(null);
```

but, still turn light on webcam(integrated with microphone) . the reason is 'microphone'

so, I try ,

```
netstream.attachAudio(null);
```

but, still turn light on webcam.

how to turn off the 'microphone' ??

Comment: How are you using the microphone? `Microphone.getMicrophone()`??  Did you attach the camera to more than one object? - you need to detach from all video/netstreams that you used attachCamera on.

Comment: I used "mic = Microphone.getEnhancedMicrophone();" .

Comment: but, when I use " mic = Microphone.getMicrophone();" , the light on webcam turned off.

Comment: I'm wondering, when " mic = Microphone.getEnhancedMicrophone();" , how to turn off the mic?

Answer (score 0):

Few things you may wanna try:

- microphone.setLoopBack(false);
- microphone.gain = 0;
- microphone = null;

Cheers,

Comment: does it works? Let us know, feedback is important so the next person looking for this will know if it works or not.